# how to make a countdown progress bar going down continuously?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

I am using a count down progress bar in android. I want it to be updated with the new time without stopping. It is now working with me but it stops for a short time then jump a part in the progress I don't want that I want it to be always decreasing without stopping.

This is my xml  code :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/timerProgressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
    android:max="20"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:progress="20" />
```

and this is the java code :

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(21000, 1) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                index++;
                timerProgressBar.setProgress((int)millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                index++;
                timerProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                navigate();
            }

        };
```

Comment: `CountDownTimer(21000, 1)` don't you mean `1000`. 1 means 1 millis?.

Comment: I made it 1 because I want it to be updated every one millisecond

Comment: Updating progress every 1 millisecond is too much overhead. `setProgress` is a UI operation and it might take more than 1 miliisecond. Try setting it to maybe 200. It will still look smooth

Comment: I changed it but that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this. Showing a 30-second countdown:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            index++;
            timerProgressBar.setProgress((int)millisUntilFinished/1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
          index++;
          timerProgressBar.setProgress(0);
          navigate();
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: This will make it update the progress Bar every Second but I want it to be shown to the user always updating .

Comment: See another answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should not run a busy loop like you are doing. The app might locks up. You need to let the rest of the system continue to do its work. Also, the fastest that the human eye can track is 30 milliseconds or so. The below timer counts milliseconds up to 10. You can set the maximum count up value by changing
if(mcount==yourvalue).

```
long seconds=0;
long millis=0;
int mCount=0;
Timer timer;

//timer textview
timeflg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerflg);

timer = new Timer();
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timerMethod();
       }
}, 1,100);

//method
private void timerMethod(){
   this.runOnUiThread(generate);
}
private Runnable generate= new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         timeflg.setText("TIME "+ seconds + ":" + mCount);
         mCount++;
         if(mCount==10){
            mCount=0;
            second++;
         }
     }
};
```

Comment: second++ should be second(s)++

Comment: the time in the textView updated every 1/10 seconds but the progress bar still updating every 1 second

Comment: Then I guess Progress Bar update event has a limitation kind of low priority thread. Not sure though.